# JavaEE vs Java под android

Tags: java, android, java-ee

Добрый день. У меня вопрос, сразу попрошу не разводить холивар, 
принципиальные различия между JavaEE и Java под Android(с той точки зрения, чтобы мне, как человеку имеющему желание программировать на java, определить что лучше выбрать)

- какова сейчас ситуация с перспективой разработки под android на java(скажем ближайшие 5 лет)
- где ниже порог входа?
- каков минимальный набор знаний туда и туда?
- если можно, по одному примеру проектика для ЕЕ и для андроида(не самого сложного, чтобы был посилен мне одному и делался не 2 года и в идеале более менее приближенного к тому, что реально делается на "работе", я имею ввиду по тематике и по задействованным технологиям), который можно делать самому и сделав который он может послужить кое- каким "портфолио" (то есть чтобы было что показать)

Спасибо.

Comment: Если ты думаешь о пороге входа, то ты уже боишься каких-то сложностей. Хочешь что бы пару уроков посмотрел и побежал бабло зарабатывать. Такого не бывает. В любом случае тебе придётся потратить много времени на изучение (через это проходят все). А финиша в этом изучении нет, т.к. технологии развиваются постоянно. Поговорка "век живи - век учись" - это про программистов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сравнивать JavaEE и разработку под андроид - все равно, что сравнивать вождение БЕЛАЗа и мотоцикла. Это совершенно разные вещи, и там, и там есть свои нюансы и сложности.
Не нужно выбирать технологию по принципу "где порог входа ниже и нужно меньше знаний". Если вам нужно "побыстрее и попроще", то научитесь клепать сайты на какой-нибудь CMS а ля Wordpress, Joomla и т.д., будет быстро и просто.

Comment: подскажите, что в основном делается на ее и что на андроиде(хотя бы примерно)

Comment: @SaintGeorge На ЕЕ делаются приложения для бизнеса. И бывает так, что по 2 года и командой из 10 человек, а не по быстрому в одиночку. Как пример, open-source ECM-система Alfresco.
На андроиде - открываете Google Play и смотрите, какие там приложения.